# local file taking precedence when external library imports dependency

Tags: python

I have 2 local files, `strategy.py` and `signal.py`

```
$ ls -1 ~/src/foo
signal.py
strategy.py
```

**`strategy.py`:**

```
$ cat strategy.py
import numpy
```

**`signal.py`:**

```
$ cat signal.py 
import talib
```

Apart from these single import lines, both files are otherwise empty.

When I attempt to run `strategy.py`, the local `signal.py` is taking precedence when one of numpy's dependencies attempts to `import signal`

```
$ python strategy.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strategy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  ...
  File "/home/steve/src/foo/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .main import TestProgram, main
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/home/steve/src/foo/signal.py", line 1, in <module>
    import talib
  File "/home/steve/src/foo/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/talib/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from ._ta_lib import (
  File "__init__.pxd", line 163, in init talib._ta_lib
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

If I rename my local file to something else, the above error doesn't occur

```
$ mv signal.py signal_foo.py
$ python strategy.py 
$ echo $?
0
```

**Questions:**

- Is there any way to solve this other than requiring I pick a unique filename?
- If so, how can I be sure that my filenames won't clash in the future, requiring me to pick another unique filename?

**Notes:**

I am running within a `virtualenv`, and am using `python-3.6.5`

Comment: An ugly solution will be to edit `sys.path` in the beginning of executing file as:

`import sys
import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    sys.path.remove(file_path)
    sys.path.append(file_path)`

Someone else might be able to provide a better answer than this dirty solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is per the [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
>   PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
>   shell variable PATH). the installation-dependent default.
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify `sys.path`. The
>   directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning
>   of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means
>   that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of
>   the same name in the library directory.

So, one answer is that you can manipulate `sys.path`, putting whichever directory you want to use first in the list.  But, this doesn't really solve your long term issue.

A better approach would be to organize your own code into [Packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using
>   “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a
>   submodule named B in a package named A.

If you put your `signal.py` in a package `myPkg`, you could then import it specifically, using;

```
import myPkg.signal
```

This still might not solve all issues if you import both signal modules into the same script.  However, you can assign a new module name on [import](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html) using;

```
import myPkg.signal as mySignal
```

In a working directory create this structure;

```
/path/to/myPkg/
    __init__.py
    signal.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

In `test.py`  put something like this

```
print '1'
import signal

print '2'
import myPkg.signal as ms
```

Now, to run this you want to add `myPkg` to `PYTHONPATH`, or for a quick check try it in the interpreter.  NOTE: the `cd` to the parent directory of `myPkg`, not into `myPkg`.

```
cd /path/to
python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-cygwin', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>> sys.path.append('./myPkg')
>>> import myPkg.tests.test
1
2
>>> quit()
```

Comment: Re packaging: What happens if `signal` is part of the current package? That is, `test.py` and `signal.py` logically live in the same package, and are therefore in the same local directory. When importing `myPkg.test` I would have the same issue wouldn't I?

Comment: Note also that the `signal` being imported is from `/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/signals.py`, and is not under my control. So the only choice is to manipulate `sys.path`?

Comment: Try putting test.py in it's own submodule; `myPkg/test/test.py`.  I'll add to my answer above.

Comment: `test.py` was an unfortunate choice of filename, as it was named because I was *testing* this error. I have updated my question and renamed the filename to show both files logically live in the same directory. Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: `foo_test.py` is conventional as a place to put your tests for the module `foo`, if you want to try to adopt some habits that might help to avoid this in the future.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy updated my question to show that my choice of filename `test.py` was an unfortunate accident, unrelated to the issue I'm experiencing

Comment: @SteveLorimer You are correct, as long as `strategy` and `signal` are in the same package, you'll have that issue.  The strategy is still to split them out into reasonable sub-modules that fit the way you think about your code. Something like this maybe; `myPkg/strategies/strategy.py` and `myPkg/processing/signal.py`.

Comment: @CAB thanks for the advice! Bit of a bummer IMO, but if that's how python works, c'est la vie I guess!